# How to make multiple react Route where the path is almost same except the id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-router-dom

I have an object called machines object.This object has it's unique key.Now i want to make Route like `path={"/machine" + key}` for all the machines.I am trying to do it like the following but it doesn't work

```
{Object.keys(this.state.machines).forEach((key, index) => {
  // console.log(this.state.machines[key].machineNo)
  <Route
    exact
    path={"/machine" + key}
    component={() => (
      <MachineComposition machine={this.state.machines[key]} />
    )}
  />
})}
```

Comment: pass the exact prop

Comment: What exactly isn't working as expected? Please clarify what the issue is.

Comment: Try using `.map` with a return instead of `.forEach`

Comment: @DrewReese if i hit the link it dosen't  render any thing

Comment: Hit what link? There are no links in any code in your question.

Comment: @DrewReese I mean create Route so it has a path/url . Like this http://localhost:3000/machine1.

Comment: I figured as much. The issue is that the code isn't returning any routes to be rendered, so there's nothing to link to. The URL will still update though.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

You are using `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `Array.prototype.map` to map the `this.state.machines` array to JSX. The `.forEach` callback is missing a return statement, but that wouldn't matter as `.forEach` is a void return so no routes would be returned to be rendered to the DOM anyway.

## Solution

Use `.map` to map the `machines` array to JSX. Use the `render` prop if you are passing additional props to the routed component, and don't forget to also pass along the route props (*i.e. `history`, `match`, `location`*) if the component needs them.

```
{Object.entries(this.state.machines).map(([key, machine]) => {
  return (
    <Route
      exact
      path={"/machine" + key}
      render={(props) => (
        <MachineComposition machine={machine} {...props} />
      )}
    />
  );
})}
```

### Suggestion

Since all these routes are effectively the same it would be better to render a single route where the machine key is a route path parameter, and the `MachineComposition` uses the params to access the machine key and get the specific machine.

Example:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/machine/:key"
  render={(props) => {
    const machine = this.state.machines[props.match.params.key];
    return <MachineComposition machine={machine} {...props} />
  }}
/>
```

Comment: can you explain why `path="/machine/:key"` (instead of `path='/machine/${key}` works?

Comment: @programandoconro Sure. `path="/machine/:key"` is defining a route path parameter named `key`. It's like a placeholder, so any URL path that matches this pattern, the second path segment will be assigned to `match.params.key`. If the path is `"/machine/123"` then `key` has the value `"123"`. If the path is `"/machine/T1000"` then `key` has the value `"T1000"`. It's a dynamic path.